# DateTimePicker js file not working after punlished in azure

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, azure

After I publish a website in Azure the calendar popup doesn't show on the webpage

here is the code of JScript.js file

```
function pageLoad() { $(function() {
    $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker(
{

    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",

    hourMin: 8,

    hourMax: 16,

    numberOfMonths: 2,

    minDate: 0,

    maxDate: 30
});


    $("input[id*='txtSchemaIssueDate']").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });



    $('#basic_example_2').timepicker();


    $('#slider_example_4').datetimepicker({
        controlType: 'select',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
    });


    $("input[id*='txtDate']").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });

    $("input[id*='txtDateFrom']").datetimepicker({
        controlType: 'select',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
    });}
```

it looks like there are errors in  pageLoad() and  $  it said cannot find $

here is the code of web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript.js"></script>

<link href="App_Themes/CSS/UI.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" \>
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you commented out the jquery script here

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
```

just remove the comment tags so that it is included

Comment: sorry the comment was a mistake,  I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I just used the [jquery-ui-timepicker-addon cdn link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon) from cloudflare to test this issue. Here is my demo html:

```html
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
</head>

<body>
   <input id="basic_example_1" type="text" value="" readonly>
   <input id="basic_example_2" type="text" value="" readonly>
   <input id="basic_example_3" type="text" value="" readonly>
   <input id="basic_example_4" type="text" value="" readonly>

   <script type="text/javascript">

   (function(){

      $('#basic_example_1').timepicker();

        $("#basic_example_2").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });

        $("#basic_example_3").datetimepicker({
            controlType: 'select',
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
        });

        $('#basic_example_4').datetimepicker(
        {
            timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
            hourMin: 8,
            hourMax: 16,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: 30
        });

   })();

</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

For your issue, I assumed that you'd better change your link over `HTTPS`, or you may encounter the following issue when you accessing your azure web app website over https.

[image]